# Can't manage to calculate time for percent

Tags: php

I have searched around and tested different solutions, but it seems that I don't get it to work.

In MySQL I have a table that list times for a workday:
ID, sheet_id, workhours, phonecall, meeting, coffe, education, clean (except ID, sheet_id, all fields are TIME)

First, it doesn't calculate as I want. (I have changed the code below just to be easier to see.)

```
    $sql = "SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(`workhours`))) AS totalworkhours
    , SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(`phonecall`))) AS totalphonecall
    , SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(`meeting`))) AS totalmeeting
    , SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(`coffe`))) AS totalcoffe
    , SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(`education`))) AS totaleducation
    , SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(`clean`))) AS totalclean  FROM working WHERE sheet_id = '$working_id'";
    $result = $db->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$per_workhours = $row['totalworkhours'];
echo "Total workhours: ". $per_workhours."<br />";
$per_phonecall = $row['totalphonecall'];
echo "Total phonecalls: ". $per_phonecall."<br />";
```

And so on everything seems fine...

```
Total workhours: 33:00:00
Total phonecalls: 16:53:00
Total coffe: 02:02:00
Total clean: 02:02:00
Total other: 02:02:00
Total other: 02:02:00
Total other: 02:02:00
Total other: 02:02:00
```

But this give me a big headache:

Calc1 says a total of 12 (12:18) but it should be 12:12

```
$no_time = $per_coffe + $per_clean + $other1 + $other2 + $other3 + $other4; 
echo "Calc 1: ". $no_time ." (".date('H:i', mktime($no_time)).")<br />";

$per_time = $per_workhousrs - $no_time;
$percent = round(($per_time/$per_workhours)*100);
```

I did simplify the code for much repeating. But I want to sum all times. Substract non wanted time and calculate real workhours in percent.

Comment: What is inside `$per_coffe` and `$per_clean` into your example?

Comment: The total is 02:02:00 for coffe and  02:02:00 for clean. And same value in 4 other fields as weel not showing in code.

Comment: If both variables are strings with `02:02:00` values - then `$no_time = $per_coffe + $per_clean;` gives `4`.

Comment: I shortened the code. There is 6 fields, each has 02:02:00 as value just for testing. But it should not give 4 even with the two first fields, it should give 04:04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Flying said, if you are adding string values, php will extract the initial digits (in this case the hours part) and add those, discarding everything else.

You can convert your time strings to seconds and back again using these functions (similar to MySQL's `TIME_TO_SEC` and `SEC_TO_TIME` functions):

```
function timeToSeconds($time)
{
    $sign = 1;
    if (strncmp($time, '-', 1) === 0) {
        $time = substr($time, 1);
        $sign = -1;
    }
    list($hours, $minutes, $seconds) = explode(':', $time, 3) + array(0, 0, 0);
    return $sign * (($hours * 3600) + ($minutes * 60) + $seconds);
}

function secondsToTime($seconds)
{
    $sign = '';
    if ($seconds < 0) {
        $sign = '-';
        $seconds = -$seconds;
    }
    $hours = floor($seconds / 3600);
    $seconds %= 3600;
    $minutes = floor($seconds / 60);
    $seconds %= 60;
    return sprintf('%s%02d:%02d:%02d', $sign, $hours, $minutes, $seconds);
}
```

Your code could then be modified to:

```
$no_time = timeToSeconds($per_coffe) + timeToSeconds($per_clean) + timeToSeconds($other1) + timeToSeconds($other2) + timeToSeconds($other3) + timeToSeconds($other4);
echo "Calc 1: ". $no_time ." (". secondsToTime($no_time) . ")<br />";

$per_time = timeToSeconds($per_workhours) - $no_time;
$percent = round(($per_time/timeToSeconds($per_workhours))*100);
echo $percent . "%<br />";
```

Which (using the values in your example) should give:

```
Calc 1: 43920 (12:12:00)
63%
```

It might be easier to modify your SQL query to return the values in seconds which you can then add directly in PHP, and format for display using only the `secondsToTime()` function.

Comment: I had no idea that php only extract the initial digits. I will check your solution later today astrangeloop.

Comment: It worked! Thank you!
But it doesnt like if some fields are NULL.

Comment: The function gives an error in
 list($hours, $minutes, $seconds) = explode(':', $time, 3);

Notice: Undefined offset: 2

Comment: I have updated my answer to handle this, by changing one line in the `timeToSeconds()` function: `list($hours, $minutes, $seconds) = explode(':', $time, 3) + array(0, 0, 0);`

Comment: Actually astrangeloop, you did save my day! Thank you!